# ElasticSearch - How to Aggregate the Geometric Mean?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently aggregating records to get the average (arithmetic average) of a field in the returned records. My use case requires me to get hold of the geometric average:

> The geometric mean is defined as the nth root of the product of n

How could I go about getting this value? I don't even know where to start!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not trivial, but it can be done. The idea is to use a sum of logs and then apply the n-th root:

```
pow(exp((sum of logs)), 1/n)
```

In fact, [GeometricMean](http://jprante.github.io/elasticsearch-index-termlist/apidocs/org/xbib/elasticsearch/common/termlist/math/GeometricMean.html) aggregation of [Elasticsearch Index Termlist Plugin](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-index-termlist) does exactly that. (However, this is a third-party plugin, I can't tell if it is stable enough.)

#### Mapping and sample data

Let's assume we have the following mapping:

```
PUT geom_mean
{
  "mappings": {
    "nums": {
      "properties": {
        "x": {
          "type": "double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And we insert the following documents:

```
{"x":33}
{"x":324}
{"x":134}
{"x":0.1}
```

Now we can try the query.

#### The ES query

Here is the query to calculate geometric mean:

```
POST geom_mean/nums/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "aggs_root": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "'Bazinga!'"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_log_x": {
          "sum": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "Math.log(doc.x.getValue())"
            }
          }
        },
        "geom_mean": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "sum_log_x": "sum_log_x",
              "x_cnt": "_count"
            },
            "script": "Math.pow(Math.exp(params.sum_log_x), 1 / params.x_cnt)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The return value will be:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "aggs_root": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Bazinga!",
          "doc_count": 4,
          "sum_log_x": {
            "value": 11.872505784215674
          },
          "geom_mean": {
            "value": 19.455434622111177
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Now a bit of explanation. Aggregation `sum_log_x` computes the sum of `x`. Aggregation named `geom_mean` is a [sibling pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-aggregations-pipeline.html) which is applied on the result of `sum_log_x` aggregation (its sibling). It uses special bucket path `_count` to get the number of elements. ([Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) you can read about `bucket_script` aggregation a bit more.)

The final trick is to wrap both of them with some aggregation, because, as explained in [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14656), `bucket_script` cannot be a top-level aggregation. Here I do a `terms` aggregation on a script that always returns `'Bazinga!'`

Thanks to [anhzhi](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14656#issuecomment-254420443) who proposed this hack.

#### Important considerations

Since the geometric mean is computed through logs, all `x` values should be greater than 0. However:

- if any of values are < 0, the result is `"NaN"`
- if all values are non-negative and less than `"+Infinity"`, but at least one value is 0, the result is `"-Infinity"`
- if both `"+Infinity"` and `"-Infinity"` are among the values, the result is `"NaN"`.

The queries were tested with Elasticsearch 5.4. Performance on a large collection of documents was not tested, you might consider inserting `x` together with its log to make aggregations more efficient.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is a top-level answer. Thanks Nikolay, if I could up-vote it 10 times I would! I had finally got ES calculating geometric means using Scripted Metric Aggregations, but your solution is so much more elegant I'm going to have to swap it out. Great work.

Comment: @user1051849 Thanks, I really liked the question! Non trivial problem.